# Opposite of "satellite"

Tags: antonyms

A satellite is an object which orbits another, what it the word for a object which is being orbited?

The moon is a satellite of Earth, the Earth is a *_*_ of the moon?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The thing that an orbiting body orbits is called that orbiting body’s *primary*.

Quoth [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_satellite):

> A **natural satellite**, or **moon**, is a celestial body that orbits another body, e.g. a planet, which is called its *primary*.